# Matlab - How to display roots of a polynomial as multiplied terms?

Tags: matlab

I have following code:

```
roots([0.00995 -0.02786 0.03611 -0.0293 0.01565  -0.005669 0.001274 -0.0001554])
```

Which results in following:

```
1.0001e+00 + 0.0000e+00i
2.8235e-01 + 4.3896e-01i
2.8235e-01 - 4.3896e-01i
3.4409e-01 + 3.9169e-01i
3.4409e-01 - 3.9169e-01i
2.7349e-01 + 3.6892e-01i
2.7349e-01 - 3.6892e-01i
```

How can I display my polynomial as the multiplication of single order terms i.e.:

```
(z-1.0001)(z-0.28235-0.43896i)(z-0.28235+0.43896i)(z-0.34409-0.39169i)(z-0.34409+0.39169i)(z-0.27349-0.36892i)(z-0.27349+0.36892i)
```

I know I can iterate through a loop and form a string variable but I was wondering if there is better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `num2str` individually on each element:

```
cell2mat(strcat('(z', arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x, '%+f'), -r, 'uni', 0), ')')')
```

gives

```
(z-1.000147)(z-0.282353-0.438959i)(z-0.282353+0.438959i)(z-0.344086-0.391687i)(z-0.344086+0.391687i)(z-0.273487-0.368920i)(z-0.273487+0.368920i)
```

You can apply `num2str` on the whole array but then you get imaginary part for real roots because it considers the whole array as complex-valued.

Using `%+f` format specifier forces it to add a `+` sign when the value is positive.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
r = roots([0.00995 -0.02786 0.03611 -0.0293 0.01565  -0.005669 0.001274 -0.0001554]);
```

Then

```
sprintf('(z-%.5f%+.5fi)',[real(r),imag(r)]')
```

This will still display a component equal to `0`. If you want to get rid of that then I think that a for-loop will be the best (most readable) solution.

Comment: not exactly. This method generate some redundant terms in the answer. Above solution was neater. Thanks for the contribution anyway.